# How to get the list of event sources attached to AWS lambda function python?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

How to get the list of event sources attached to a given AWS lambda function ARN in python boto3

Comment: The `get_policy` call? https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/lambda.html#Lambda.Client.get_policy

Answer (score 0):

Didn't try this one out. But check this:

[list_event_source_mappings](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/lambda.html#Lambda.Client.list_event_source_mappings)

Pass the `FunctionName`.

**FunctionName (string)** --

> The name of the Lambda function.
>
> You can specify the function name (for example, Thumbnail ) or you can
>   specify Amazon Resource Name (ARN) of the function (for example,
>   arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:account-id:function:ThumbNail )